# Conseguir todas las palabras entre varias etiquetas

Tags: python

tengo un script de Python que recolecta toda la información desde `<dat>` hasta `</dat>` lo he hecho funcionar pero solo funciona con un par de etiquetas (No puedo utilizar modulos, si no ya hubiese usado Beautiful Soup):

```
word = """
outside
<dat>
Hello
how
it's
going
</dat>
outside
"""

sidx = word.index('<dat>')+len('<dat>')+1
eidx = word.index('</dat>')-1

data = word[sidx:eidx]
print(data)
```

esto funciona correctamente pero si cambio:

```
word = """
outside
<dat>
Hello
how
</dat>
middle
<dat>
it's
going
</dat>
outside
"""
```

solo devuelve el primer par de etiquetas:

```
Hello
how
```

como puedo hacer para conseguir el contenido de todas las etiquetas y no solo una

Comment: @HeytalePazguato el primer fragmento de código funciona, necesito saber como hacer eso pero con mas de 2 etiquetas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta función procesa un texto con marcas. Para ello divide el texto en palabras usando `split()`.

La variable `salida` es la lista de los trozos extraídos. Cada elemento es una sublista con las palabras del trozo en cuestión.

La variable `trozo` contiene la lista en formación con el contenido entre el `<dat>` y el `</dat>` actual. Esta variable es `None` cuando se mira una palabra fuera de las etiquetas. Cuando se detecta el comienzo de un trozo (`<dat>`), `trozo` se inicializa con una lista vacía.

Toda palabra leída cuando `trozo` es una lista, se agrega a ella.

Cuando se encuentra un `<\dat>`, se agrega `trozo` a `salida` antes de volverlo a `None`, lo que señala que estamos fuera de las etiquetas:

```
def extraer(xml):
    salida = []
    trozo = None
    for palabra in xml.split():
        if palabra == "<dat>":
            trozo = []
        elif palabra == "</dat>":
            salida.append(trozo)
            trozo = None
        elif trozo is not None:
            trozo.append(palabra)

return salida
```

**Demo**

```
word = """
outside
<dat>
Hello
how
</dat>
middle
<dat>
it's
going
</dat>
outside
"""

print(extraer(word))
```

produce:

```
[['Hello', 'how'], ["it's", 'going']]
```